# What is the difference between android intents?

Tags: android, android-intent

What’s the difference between an intent used for `startActivity()` and an intent used for the `sendBroadcast()` method? In a tutorial, I found an way for dynamically registering a broadcast receiver. For this purpose, I had to provide a string as my intent name. How to choose an intent name in this case and use for `sendBroadcast()` or `registerReceiver()`?

Should I add something to my `android_manifest.xml` file? according to the tutorial, I have currently declared an intent name like this:

```
private static final String SEARCH_ACTION = "com.example.usingwebservices.rest.SEARCH";
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(SEARCH_ACTION));
}
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(progress!=null){
            progress.dismiss();
        }
        String response = intent.getStringExtra(RestTask.HTTP_RESPONSE);
        result.setText(response);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you do right thing. there are two methods to register receiver, following [enter link description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html):

```
You can either dynamically register an instance of this class with Context.registerReceiver() or statically publish an implementation through the <receiver> tag in your AndroidManifest.xml.
```

and the message to queue in service maybe like :

```
 Intent i = new Intent("com.example.usingwebservices.rest.SEARCH");
 i.putExtra(RestTask.HTTP_RESPONSE, "msgdetails");
 context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

the intent's contruction ,the parameter is an action name:

```
Intent(String action)
```

and when used startActivity, the contruction I used:

```
Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

you can see reference of Intent following [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html):

and I think Google want package the most msg format .

Comment: so is it enough to use the same action name for sendBroadcast() and registerReceiver() to get broadcasting-receiving process done? or i have to register this action-name somewhere else for permission or any other purposes.

Comment: yes, you can. intent has two method: setAction & setClass. But I think maybe package two types parameter into one intent is not a good idea,except for they are the actually same thing.